# AlarmManager run at specific time of the day in emulator

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

If i sett HOUR=11 and MINUTE=00, it wont run at time 11:00 in my emulator, is something wrong here?:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyService.class), 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MINUTE);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000, pintent);
running = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This alarm will be work 11:00am..

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,  MyService.class);
    PendingIntent penintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

      //Here I have set it to 11.00am

         Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
         cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
         cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
         cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        //set timer as a RTC Wakeup to alarm manager object
     alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, penintent);
```

I suggest, try to use this solution.

Comment: but, i want it to repeat at the same time every day

Comment: Isn't that basicly what i've got?

Comment: @KimVu Use Boradcast receiver for same